# What happens when battery is fully charged in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: battery, msi

I have a **MSI GL63** laptop. Under Windows I can have it **all the time connected to the current and the battery does not suffer any damage (affirmed by MSI)**. But I installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 for software development and I wonder how the current management works in this system since it does not show the message "Connected but not loading" as Windows does.

Can I also have connected to power even after charge the battery completely in Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK The battery charging thresholds are hardware dependent.  There are some notable exceptions, such as the Thinkpad line of computers in which the upper level of battery charge can be set in Ubuntu, but controlling the rate of charge is usually performed by the laptop hardware.

As a thought exercise, what happens to your Windows laptop when Windows is off, but the computer is plugged into a wall?  Does it 'overcharge'?  Windows is not running (the computer is off).

If power management is a concern for your computer, consider using [TLP](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-improve-ubuntu-laptop-power-management.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/battery-and-charging), charging is managed independently by the hardware without any intervention from the operating system. This means that everything should work exactly the same regardless of which operating system is used. You may not get a message in the user interface, but that doesn't change what's actually happening in the hardware.

Also, my personal experience is that this isn't a problem. I have been keeping my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu constantly connected to the charger every workday, with no ill effects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,  if you know any way to control the speed of the coolers, I would appreciate it if you would share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Batteries are hard ware not soft ware - as such understand your battery (based on its type) will have a set number of cycles (charge/drain) that it can survive. Each cycle reduces battery life and charge capacity.

Based on battery type it may be better to fully discharge/recharge your battery, OR to keep it always above 80% charge

But in the end its way to inconvenient time wise to screw with that - just leave it plugged in - should be good for a year or two (they are built to fail after two years intentionally so you have to buy a new one... so don't sweat the small stuff)